# List of all allowed html tags in CKEditor 4

Tags: html, tags, ckeditor

I need a full list of all allowed html tags in CKEditor 4 after using parameter:
config.allowedContent = true;
Can someone provide me this list? :)

Comment: No, however Google may be able to.

Comment: I think that the question should be made more precise. I tried to answer it, but you could have something else in mind.

Answer (score 0):

When the Advanced Content Filter is disabled, then CKEditor does not filter the content. It may, however, slightly correct it according to the editor's [DTD](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd). The DTD was created for HTML5 with some extensions and without support for ["transparent elements"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent).

Answer (score 0):

some general tags are:

`get_header()`, `get_enter code here`, `get_sidebar()`, `get_template_part()`, `get_search_form()`

For more Information [click here](http://psds2wp.com/)